# Using a select-box with Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find a suitable way for Selenium to select an item within a `select-box`.

I have tried using:

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select-box[@name='countryCode']"))).selectByVisibleText(country);
```

but get the expected error of:

```
org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "select-box"
```

Trying to use `WebElement` works great to select the element, but not able to "search" the results for the correct item list.

This is the HTML I am working with that I have simplified a bit:

```
<select-box name="type" options="$ctrl.ClubTypes"
  track-by="value" label-by="label" required="">
  <div class="SelectBox">
    <div>
      <div></div>
      <input readonly="" class="Input " type="text" value="Club">
    </div>
    <ul class="SelectBox-options ng-scope" ng-if="$ctrl.isShowingOptions" style="">
      <li>Country list items</li> 
    </ul>
  </div>
</select-box>
```

I am fairly new to using Selenium and programming in general so any help would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select-box[@name='countryCode']"))).selectByVisibleText(country);
```

Just try

```
String contry = "IRAN";
    
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='SelectBox']")).findElement(By.xpath(".//li[contains(text(),'" + country + "')]"))
```

Comment: Thank you for that! Works a charm!

Answer (score 1):

This exception

```
org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "select-box"
```

basically means is, that you are trying to use `Select` class from `Selenium`, (which is **solely** meant for `drop downs` built using `Select` and `option` tag).

If you pay attention to the HTML that you have shared, There **isn't** any `Select` Instead it is `select-box`

**Solution :**

1. Try to click on drop down first, then once options are visible click directly to the desired options as well.

**Code trial 1 :**

```
Thread.sleep(5);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select-box[@name='countryCode']")).click();
```

**Code trial 2 :**

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//select-box[@name='countryCode']"))).click();
```

use any one of them and it would click on drop down, and then you can select your desired option in similar way.

I would need to see the `outerHTML` first to find the reliable locator to `click` on `option`.

Comment: Thanks for that, Good to know that I can include a ```wait``` instead of having to have a new line just to do that!